# How do I write a Regular Expression to match any three digit number value?

Tags: regex

I'm working with some pretty funky HTML markup that I inherited, and I need to remove the following attributes from about 72 `td` elements.

```
sdval="285"
```

I know I can do this with find/replace in my code editor, except since the value of each attribute is different by 5 degree increments, I can't match them all without a Regular Expression. (FYI I'm using Esspress and it does support RegExes in it's Find/Replace tool)

Only trouble is, I really can't figure out how to write a RegEx for this value. I understand the concept of RegExes, but really don't know how to use them.

So how would I write the following with a Regular Expression in place of the digits so that it would match any three digit value?

```
sdval="285"
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
/sdval="\d{3}"/
```

EDIT:

To answer your comment, `\d` in regular expressions means `match any digit`, and the `{n}` construct means `repeat the previous item n times.`

Comment: That was perfect. Thank you!! Also, if you don't mind - can you explain the \d{3} part of the expression for me?

Answer (score 21):

Easiest, most portable: `[0-9][0-9][0-9]`

More "modern": `\d{3}`

Comment: @simshaun - Back when I learned regex, the {n} and {n,m} repeaters weren't there.  I'm not sure every regex library supports them yet.  That's why I called my first one "most portable".

Comment: @PaulTomblin I am getting `None` for lines 20 to 22 here:  https://github.com/nyck33/tennisball-tracker/blob/master/parse-json.py where I just want 3 digit integers (from 0 to 999) and no other matches.

Comment: @mLstudent33 “0” is not a three digit integer.

Comment: @PaulTomblin, sorry I meant 100 but I was able to figure it out.  It was something like `'/b/d/d/d/b'`

Answer (score 6):

This should do (ignores leading zeros):

```
[1-9][0-9]{0,2}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import re

data = "719"
data1 = "79"

# This expression will match any single, double or triple digit Number
expression = '[\d]{1,3}'

print(re.search(expression, data).string)

# This expression will match only triple digit Number
expression1 = '[\d]{3}'

print(re.search(expression1, data1).string)
```

**Output :**

> expression : 719
>
> expression1 : 79

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to do a find / replace in Visual Studio of a 3 digit number (references to Express and Find/Replace tool).  If that's the case the regex to find a 3 digit number in Visual Studio is the following

```
<:d:d:d>
```

Breakdown

- The `<` and `>` establish a word boundary to make sure we don't match a number subset.
- Each `:d` entry matches a single digit.